# Splitting principle for real vector bundles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, characteristic-classes

I'm reading the Book of John Roe, *Elliptic Operators, Topology and Asymptotic Methods* and got stuck at Lemma 2.27.

i) How does this lemma show that a real vector bundle can be given by a pullback of direct sums of plane bundles?

ii) Assuming i) is clear, is this equation $\Pi_f(h^*E) = \prod_j g(p_1(P_j))$ then true for suitable real 2-plane bundles $P_j$ in which $h^*$ splits as direct sum?

iii) What happens in odd dimensions? Has it something to do with choosing $g(0)=1$?

I appreciate some literature or concise explaination. :)

EDIT: I've found a good reference [1]. Namely Proposition 11.2 together with Observation 11.8 gives a satisfying answer for me.

[1] H. Blaine Lawson and Marie-Louise Michelsohn. Spin Geometry.

Comment: I don't understand your question (i). Obviously the pullback of a sum of plane bundles is again a sum of plane bundles, and not every even-dimensional bundle is of this form (for instance, pick a vector bundle such as $TS^8$ which doesn't have a complex structure). In your source, the lemma is proved by formal manipulation of symmetric functions.

Comment: As discussed there, you can also use the following real splitting principle: To any metrized real vector bundle $E\to X$ associate the flag bundle $p:F_E\to X$ whose fiber over $x$ are maximal collections (so of size $\lfloor \frac{\operatorname{dim}(E)}{2}\rfloor$) of mutually orthogonal $2$-dimensional  subspaces of $E_x$. The map $p^*:H^*(X)\to H^*(F_E)$ is injective, and $p^*E$ splits as a sum of plane bundles and possibly one plane bundle, so that it suffices to check an identity between characteristic classes for bundles of this form.

Comment: The very last comment did answer my first question partially. Do you have a source on that?

Comment: As explained in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/splitting+principle it boils down to the fact that for a compact connected Lie group $G$ with maximal torus $T$, the map $H^*(BG;\mathbb Q)\to H^*(BT;\mathbb Q)$ is injective (in fact, it is the inclusion of invariants under the Weyl group). See the link for integral statements.

Comment: @YoungMath Starts at page 66 of [this reference](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VBpage.html). There the proof is given for K-theory, but it works verbatim for ordinary cohomology (and indeed for any complex orientable cohomology theory).

Comment: This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4275049/lawson-and-michelsohns-proof-of-the-splitting-principle-for-oriented-vector-bun) is related. I believe that there is no perfect analogue of the complex splitting principle in the real world (for arbitrary coefficients).